# Elixir: How to use JOSE.JWK.to_file to save a key file for use with Guardian / JWT Authentication

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I am using [Guardian](https://github.com/ueberauth/guardian) to set up JWT authentication. It is recommended to use a JWK (Json Web Key) to encrypt / sign the JWT. To generate said JWK I use [JOSE.JWK](https://hexdocs.pm/jose/JOSE.JWK.html).

Since my key file will be probably stored in source control, I want it to be password protected. The password is passed into the elixir app via `System.get_env` (to access environment variables).

I can generate the file and also read it back in with a password. But it fails in my config files like `config/dev.exs`. The error is

** (Mix.Config.LoadError) could not load config config/dev.exs
    ** (CompileError) config/dev.exs:2: module JOSE.JWK is not loaded and could not be found

My dev.exs:

```
use Mix.Config

# Configure Guardian for JWT Authentication
config :guardian, Guardian,
  allowed_algos: ["HS512"], # optional
  verify_module: Guardian.JWT,  # optional
  issuer: "MyApp",
  ttl: { 30, :days },
  verify_issuer: true, # optional
  secret_key:  System.get_env("GUARDIAN_KEY_PASSPHRASE") |> JOSE.JWK.from_file(System.get_env("GUARDIAN_KEY_FILE")),
  serializer: MyApp.GuardianSerializer
```

In the console everything works fine. So I guess when the config files are parsed, the modules aren't loaded yet. Is there a way to solve this?

**Edit:**
It seems to have to do with when modules are loaded and how and when configuration files are evaluated and compiled. Wrapping the calls to `JSON.JWK` in an anonymous function for example works:

```
use Mix.Config

# Configure Guardian for JWT Authentication
config :guardian, Guardian,
  allowed_algos: ["HS512"], # optional
  verify_module: Guardian.JWT,  # optional
  issuer: "MyApp",
  ttl: { 30, :days },
  verify_issuer: true, # optional
  secret_key: fn -> System.get_env("GUARDIAN_KEY_PASSPHRASE") |> JOSE.JWK.from_file(System.get_env("GUARDIAN_KEY_FILE")) end,
  serializer: MyApp.GuardianSerializer
```

Comment: This might be obvious, but I need to ask. Have you added `{:jose, "~> 1.7"}, {:poison, "~> 2.1"}` to deps in `mix.exs` and run `mix deps.get`?

Comment: @tkowal `JOSE` is of course in the dependencies and it also works in the console. I think it has to do with how and when the configuration is loaded and compiled and when modules are loaded. I updated my question accordingly

Comment: By "works in console" you mean it works in `iex`? This is strange, because `iex` uses the same config. One more obvious thing I have to ask :P Have you run `mix compile`? I believe `iex -S mix run` can compile modules in the path on demand while `mix run` can't.

Comment: I mean `iex`, sorry, old Rails habits... The thing is: It will not compile if I don't wrap the calls in an anonymous function, that is the problem. It fails with the error that `JOSE.JWK` is not available.

Comment: Is it possible to share the app with us? Or minimal example at least? I would like to play with it to check what happens under the hood.

Comment: I think what happens is that at compilation first the config is evaluated before any dependencies are included. I asked a similar / broader question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36713069/elixir-phoenix-how-to-use-third-party-modules-in-config-files/36715368#36715368)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only the master branch of Guardian supports functions in the config.exs   file.  The released versions (0.10.x) do not support functions.

The issue is being tracked here: https://github.com/ueberauth/guardian/issues/136.
You can see the new code here:
https://github.com/ueberauth/guardian/blob/master/lib/guardian.ex#L292-296, especially line 294

Comment: Thanks. I actually raised that issue myself :)