# Elixir/Phoenix: How to use third-party modules in config files?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

It seems that the way configuration files in phoenix are loaded and compiled pose a problem when using third-party modules in `config.exs` or `dev.exs/prod.exs/test.exs`.

Example: To set up [Guardian](https://github.com/ueberauth/guardian) for JWT authentication I am trying to use the [`JOSE.JWK`](https://hexdocs.pm/jose/JOSE.JWK.html) module for JWK creation / loading in my `config.exs`. I can use the module alright in the console with `iex -S mix phoenix.server`. It is of course installed as a dependency. The error I'm getting is

```
** (Mix.Config.LoadError) could not load config config/config.exs
    ** (UndefinedFunctionError) undefined function JOSE.JWK.from_file/2 (module JOSE.JWK is not available)
```

This is the code in my config.exs

```
# Configure Guardian for JWT Authentication
config :guardian, Guardian,
  allowed_algos: ["HS512"], # optional
  verify_module: Guardian.JWT,  # optional
  issuer: "MyApp",
  ttl: { 30, :days },
  verify_issuer: true, # optional
  secret_key: System.get_env("GUARDIAN_KEY_PASSPHRASE") |> JOSE.JWK.from_file(System.get_env("GUARDIAN_KEY_FILE")),
  serializer: MyApp.GuardianSerializer
```

It works when I wrap the call to `JOSE.JWK.from_file/2` in an anonymous function. But of course the value of Guardian.config(:secret_key) is then the anonymous function itself and not its return value:

```
# Configure Guardian for JWT Authentication
config :guardian, Guardian,
  allowed_algos: ["HS512"], # optional
  verify_module: Guardian.JWT,  # optional
  issuer: "MyApp",
  ttl: { 30, :days },
  verify_issuer: true, # optional
  secret_key: fn -> System.get_env("GUARDIAN_KEY_PASSPHRASE") |> JOSE.JWK.from_file(System.get_env("GUARDIAN_KEY_FILE")) end,
  serializer: MyApp.GuardianSerializer
```

This is ok in this example since Guardian accepts a function for this config value. But I can imagine other situations where this could be a problem.

Is this limitation on purpose? Am I missing something? Is there a way around this?

Comment: A workaround I will settle with for now is this: put `Code.load_file("config/support.exs")` into the top of `config/config.exs`, and place _.exs_ code with helper functions there. I'm aware that's not a satisfying answer, but there seems to be none.

Answer (score 21):

Since configuration is evaluated before the dependencies are compiled you can't use code from dependencies in the configuration.

The reason is simple: configuration could change how a dependency is compiled. You need to decide what to do first - compile to evaluate configurations. Decision has been taken to evaluate configuration first since it's far more useful (and frequent) to manipulate compilation through configs than to use dependencies to configure other applications - most frequently configuration is just raw data.

Comment: The same question applies to accessing functions from the app itself, rather than a dependency. This is causing pain at https://github.com/trenpixster/addict/issues/105

Comment: Are you sure? How does `config :my_app, MyApp.Endpoint,` work?

Comment: @asiniy `MyApp.Endpoint` is just an atom. If it was `MyApp.Endpoint.foo()`, it would be a function call and would need the dependent module to be compiled.

Answer (score 2):

If you first compile a module that lives outside of `elixirc_paths` before running mix and it's in the elixir search path, it will find it. Just do `Whatever.foo(:bar)`

It would make more sense to wrap up the pre-compilation as a mix task, and call mix to make sure config deps are up-to-date before calling a 3rd-party dep.

It would be helpful if there were a pre-config mix hook and/or a `config/lib` which is precompiled before evaluating config. Otherwise, configs will grow and become disgusting piles of code, even when using `import_config` which doesn't let you modularize and DRY out code.

Another hackaround is to have a minimal mix task which loads just enough of your app to get values and write them to stdout, and then use a Port to get them elsewhere where needed (Rails does this in places).

Comment: Many build systems actually have the notion of build vs runtime dependencies. This would possibly a reasonable distinction to add to Mix as well. It's used precisely when a language is compiled. Java, and and Javascript - compiled as it is these days - come to mind.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it is possible to do this with Mix, using archives.

They need to be installed manually, but can be built quite easily using a separate Mix project and `mix archive.build`.

They are limited in that archive projects can't have dependencies of their own.

See the docs for details. https://hexdocs.pm/mix/Mix.Tasks.Archive.Build.html#content